# Best Way to Keep JDK Up to Date within the same Major Release

Tags: java

I am currently using JDK in a Mac OS machine. I found that even for the same major release, sometimes there are some subtle differences (e.g. Java 8 update 01 vs update 51), with compiling and things, that I need to try to keep my JDK up to date for that reason.

My questions are:

1. Are there security concerns so that I should always keep my JDK up to date with every update?
2. If that is the case, what will be the best/automatic way to keep my JDK up to date?

Comment: Do you mean like updating from JDK 7 to JDK 8

Comment: I guess there is no method to automatically update. You can subscribe to their mailing list for getting regular updates though.

Comment: @rert588 no I mean to e.g. Update within different updates of Java8

Comment: for 1. it depends on what is in the changelog

Comment: how is this a programming question?

Comment: @eis it is a programming question in my opinion (I guess?), because I don't know if there are security risks if I don't keep my JDK up to date.

Comment: JRE within JDK will have security patches coming with those updates. If you use the JDK strictly for compiling and have a separate JRE for running things, which is kept up to date, in that case there probably aren't security concerns - there are other changes though. For keeping such a separate JDK up to date there probably isn't any mechanism, though I am not a user of Mac myself so this is more speculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as @eis said if I use my JDK strictly for compiling, there shouldn't be security concerns (since running the application will be in a different JRE environment). Thank you @eis!